# what is wrong with this piece of code in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct, segmentation-fault

I have 2-D map of type structure, and I want to initialize condition element of struct to enum UNKNOWN.

*the compilation is OK, but it gives segmentation fault which I can't solve.*

```
#include<stdio.h>

enum myenum {EXPLORED, UNKNOWN,}condition;
struct tile {
    int x;
    int y;
    int condition;
    };

struct tile* map[8][8];
void init_map() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            map[i][j]->condition = UNKNOWN;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void print_map() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            printf("%d ", map[i][j]->condition);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void main() {

init_map();
print_map();
}
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: You never actually initialized the pointers themselves to point to anything.

Comment: in the future run the program under a debugger - you will at least get to see where it goes bang

Comment: "I have 2-D map of type structure" - No. You have a _2D array of **pointer to** `struct`_! Which is exactly your problem! (What ever you mean with the rest of the sentence)

Answer (score 2):

The error in your program is that the `map` is an array of pointers that never were assigned to point to any objects. Hence,

```
        map[i][j]->condition = UNKNOWN;
```

and

```
        printf("%d ", map[i][j]->condition);
```

result in undefined behavior.

It's not clear why you need an array of pointers. You could just use an array of objects.

```
struct tile map[8][8]; // Drop the pointer
```

and use

```
        map[i][j].condition = UNKNOWN;
```

and

```
        printf("%d ", map[i][j].condition);
```